# generating a unique id and class for variable number of directives

Tags: angularjs

[Here's a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/caduranume/1/edit?html,js,console,output) illustrating the issue, but I will explain it also below with code. I am making a custom directive in AngularJs that will be inserted once for every entry in the database, which I iterate over using `ng-repeat` as you see here.

```
 <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as demo">

    <h1> Hello {{ name }}

<div class="some-list" ng-repeat="customer in customers">

 <div id="not-unique"  class="not-unique" my-dumb-graphic datajson=customer></div>
I need to make a unique class or id

  </div>

</div>
```

In case you didn't notice, the directive tucked into that code is `my-dumb-graph`, with the corresponding `myDumbGraphic` name in the code below. In order to insert the graphic, which I will do in the link function of the directive below, I need to be able to select a unique id or class in the html above, **and I will need to be able to select it from within the link function in the directive**, so somehow need to reference the id from the html in the js. You can see in the jsbin that inside the link function of the directive, the id is not yet unique (i.e. the dynamic part hasn't been computed yet), even though it's eventually unique by the time it's rendered to the dom.

```
<div id="not-unique"  class="not-unique" my-dumb-graphic datajson=customer></div>
```

Rest of the code
    var app = angular.module('jsbin', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {
            'use strict';

```
        var routeConfig = {
            controller: 'DemoCtrll'

        };
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', routeConfig)
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
});

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) { 
   $scope.name = "World";
   $scope.customers = [
        {
            name: 'David',
            street: '1234 Anywhere St.'
        },
        {
            name: 'Tina',
            street: '1800 Crest St.'
        },
        {
            name: 'Michelle',
            street: '890 Main St.'
        }
    ];

});
app.directive('myDumbGraphic', function () {

    return {
            restrict: 'A', 
            scope: {
                datajson: '='
            },


             link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

                ...code to insert my dumb graphic...need to select unique id or class or both...need to select unique id from here

            }
        };

    });
```

Update

As several people have suggested, there are multiple ways to create a dynamic id for a div, however, the dynamic part of the div id won't have computed by the time I need it in the link function. For example, If, following suggestion of other answer, I set id in the html to this `<div id="id_{{::id}}"` then the dynamic part of it won't have computed by the time I need it to inside the link function, although if I inspect the dom after it's rendered it has computed. In the link function, I can access the div through the elem like this "#"+elem[0].id; and log statements show that at that time it hasn't computed- this is what log statements show for "#"+elem[0].id; ----> #id_{{::id}}

Comment: you already have instances of customer objects in the directive scope. Presumably you have some unique identifier for each customer so why can't you access it's data?

Comment: @charlietfl see the update to the OP. Yes, there are many ways to create a unique identifier but when I try to set it in the html, it won't have computed by the time I need it in the link function. Example in update in OP

Comment: why do you need element ID's  at all is my point? Angular manages the DOM and you rarely need to focus on an element ID

Comment: @charlietfl I need to select an element using D3 (` d3.select(el).append('svg'); `) to insert a chart on the page for every entry that gets retrieved from the db. If I just use the static div that angular provides, when d3 selects the element, it selects the first one it finds, so all the charts get inserted for the first entry in the db, and the subsequent entries on the page don't have a chart next to them. Thereofre need unique id that d3 can select for each entry

Comment: but aren't you initializing the charts in directive and therefore have the element available in the directive? This still seems like an X-Y problem

Comment: all the chart code is in the link function of the directive, however, the dynamic part (that I created) of the elem that gets passed into the link function isn't computed yet by the time d3 tries to select it as a location where to append the svg. It's basically trying to do what you see here http://www.phloxblog.in/d3-js-angular-directive/?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=buffere1b4b&utm_medium=twitter#.VL_TTS7F8Yc, but instead of attaching one chart, it's attaching one for every entry in the db

Comment: sounds like the data calcs are in wrong sequence then and you keep trying to hack around that

Comment: Anyways, if you have time and willingness, using the jsbin I linked to above, if you know how, can you show me how to ensure that a unique id or class for each entry is available in the link function. If it's available then the problem's solved

Comment: fyi, here's a demo showing the problem jsbin.com/caduranume/1 -- if you look at the results of log statement in the link function and you can see the id isn't computed yet.

Comment: you are stuck on the element ID's which is the wrong part to focus on in my mind. Why is there a lg in having these other customer identifiers? That part makes no sense to me. The data is available in controller to do whatever is needed

Comment: I need custom ids in the dom that I can select. Yes, there's data in the controller, but d3 needs to select something from the dom to append to

Comment: We are on completely different wavelengths. If you need d3 in the ng-repeat, you have element access in directive. If it only gets fired in last ng-repeat a simple class will suffice. Just seems to me to be numerous ways to do what you need to without neediing element ID's

Comment: I don't have a preference if it's an element id or a class. Other than that, I guess I don't understand what you're saying. If you're willing to show me a demo or some code or answer the question, that would be appreciated, but if not, then per SO's warning we probably shouldn't continue the chat.

Comment: some sample d3 code that would apply to `ng-repeat` would help

Comment: for the d3 code I used this http://www.phloxblog.in/d3-js-angular-directive/?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=buffere1b4b&utm_medium=twitter#.VL_TTS7F8Yc and just created an object for the controller with some dummy values that could be graphed, see the stats property in https://gist.github.com/eac28aeaa4ce2a29ab55

Comment: but where are you initiating? If it's in the directive issue is simple. Traverse `element` to return dom element to apply chart to

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "initiating". Please show me with code if you can otherwise per SO instructions we shouldn't be chatting this much

Answer (score 2):

1. The directive link function has the corresponding element pass in as a parameter, so you already have the selector:

   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

   }
2. Alternatively, you could take leverage your $scope.customers array keys as unique ids and set view elements, pass the id into the directive, and use that as a selector (this assumes you jQuery loaded):

   ```
   <h1> Hello {{ name }} </h1>

   <!-- use customers array index -->
   <div class="some-list" ng-repeat="(customerId, customer) in customers">

     <!-- append customer id to this element id so it is unique -->
     <div id="directive-element-selector-{{customerId}}"  class="not-unique" my-dumb-graphic datajson=customer customer-array-id=customerId></div>
       <div id="inner-selector-{{customerId}">
         I need to make a unique class or id
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

directive:

```
app.directive('myDumbGraphic', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', 
    scope: {
      datajson: '=',
      customerArrayId: '='
    },

   link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

      $('#directive-element-selector-' + customerArrayId) // jQuery selector, this should equal elem pass in as link function param

      $('#inner-selector-' + customerArrayId) // inner selector

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: The computed value of a dynamic id isn't available through the elem parameter.  If, following suggestion of other answer, I set id in the html to this <div id="id_{{::id}}" then the dynamic part of it won't have computed by the time I need it to inside the link function, although if I inspect the dom after it's rendered it has computed. In the link function, I can access the div through the elem like this "#"+elem[0].id; and log statements show that at that time it hasn't computed- this is what log statements show for "#"+elem[0].id; ----> #id_{{::id}}

Comment: fyi here's a demo showing the problem jsbin.com/caduranume/1 --look at the results of log statement in the link function and you can see the id isn't computed yet

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $scope $id property which will be unique for each directive and scope in your system, so you can do something like

```
<div class="myclass_{{::$id}}"></div>
```

or something like that

Note:
the :: is for one time binding

Comment: thanks, how would I select that from within the link function, as `$scope.id`?

Comment: is just scope.$id if you are altering a current html tag or just use $id in your template

Comment: This doesn't work. If I set div I'd to   myid_{{::$id}}  then when I try to select it through elem parameter in link function the ::$id part hasn't computed yet. Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry I was on ipad earlier. This might be clearer. If I set id in the html to this `<div id="id_{{::id}}"` then the dynamic part of it won't have computed by the time I need it to inside the link function, although if I inspect the dom after it's rendered it has computed. In the link function, I can access the div through the elem like this `"#"+elem[0].id;`  and log statements show that at that time it hasn't computed- this is what log statements show for  `"#"+elem[0].id;`  ---->  `#id_{{::id}}`

Comment: here's a demo showing the problem http://jsbin.com/caduranume/1/ --look at the results of  log statement in the link function and you can see the id isn't computed yet.